# OpenCV & python convert Pixel to distance

Tags: python, opencv, distance, pixel, measurement

I have a couple of known values and using just 1 of the two does not fetch an accurate result... As seen in the image bellow i can detect the last 2 rows of circles and display an output. Each circle averages .84" +/- .005"(at worst). Also the distance between rows (y axis) should be between 1.82" and 1.96" (the given image is 1.84")

I am using an 800*600 resolution webcam to capture the image shown for processing

the way i have been going about this is to do the following:

conv_px_to_in = .84/46  (46 is what my code outputs as the average circle size in the image
 this yields a result of 0.01826087

however when trying to measure Y distance between rows i get the following
conv_px_to_in = 1.82/(514-343)  (y values seen in provided output bellow)
 this yields a result of 0.01064327

once i have the conversion number (generally i take the radius of the circle as that changes less) i then find the distances by multiplying the pixel measurement by the conv_px_to_in value to compare results. That is where i am having the issue as it of course works for the circle itself, but nothing else on the screen.... The camera is centered beneath the image taken.

How do i come up with a distance measurement that i can use in order to accurately translate pixels to inches or a form of distance?

[image: post-processed output]

CODE OUTPUT:

```
RAD = 46
Y_MAX = 514
Y_MIN = 343
[[[114 514  46]
  [114 343  47]
  [290 343  45]
  [288 514  46]
  [464 343  46]
  [464 514  46]
  [644 343  47]
  [644 514  45]]]
```

Comment: Have you tried camera calibration? This excerpt is from "Learning OpenCV": "Camera calibration is important also for relating camera measurements with measurements in the real, three-dimensional world." (page 370, chapter 11). You can read the ebook on Google Books at: http://books.google.com/books?id=seAgiOfu2EIC&printsec=frontcover&dq=learning+opencv&hl=en&sa=X&ei=63qSU47-AuaqsATSnoC4BA&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=learning%20opencv&f=false

Comment: Is it just that `.84` is the diameter of the circles while `46` is the radius? That would make you off by a factor of 2.

Comment: @MarkRansom That is correct i did overlook that, i guess that is what happens when you don't take a step back to look at something... That brings me down to an approximate 2-8% fudge factor of being off with other known values just quickly typing into the calculator. I am guessing that will get better with camera calculation that Ryan spoke of.

again thankyou MarkRansom for catching that, i will double check that .84" is the diameter and not just the radius.

Comment: @Ryan I have not looked into that yet, but it looks very interesting. I just recently got involved with object tracking and such via camera so i am a little new to this.